# Pandas add column on condition: If value of cell is True set value of largest number in Period to true

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with lets say two columns, for example:

```py
     value  boolean
0        1        0
1        5        1
2        0        0
3        3        0
4        9        1
5       12        0
6        4        0
7        7        1
8        8        1
9        2        0
10      17        0
11      15        1
12       6        0
```

Now I want to add a third column (new_boolean) with the following criteria:
I specify a period, for this example period = 4.
Now I take a look at all rows where boolean == 1.
new_boolean will be 1 for the maximum value in the last period rows.

For example I have boolean == 1 for row 2. So I look at the last period rows. The values are [1, 5], 5 is the maximum, so the value for new_boolean in row 2 will be one.

Second example: row 8 (value = 7): I get values [7, 4, 12, 9], 12 is the maximum, so the value for new_boolean in the row with value 12 will be 1

result:

```py
     value   boolean  new_boolean
0        1         0            0
1        5         1            1
2        0         0            0
3        3         0            0
4        9         1            1
5       12         0            1
6        4         0            0
7        7         1            0
8        8         1            0
9        2         0            0
10      17         0            1
11      15         1            0
12       6         0            0
```

[image]

How can I do this algorithmically?

Comment: im not sure that im understanding the problem. here a propose:
for every i boolean (enumerated),  if true -> if max ( df['value'].iloc[i-4:i]) == df['value'].iloc[i]) -> df['new_boolean'].iloc[i] = 1

Comment: Why doesn't row 10 get a 1? Its value is the max in any 4-row window which includes it...

Comment: Shouldn't row 11 `value = 15` has the `new_boolean` value to be `0` since 15 is less than 17?

Answer (score -1):

Compute the rolling max of the 'value' column

```
>>> rolling_max_value = df.rolling(window=4, min_periods=1)['value'].max()
>>> rolling_max_value 

0      1.0
1      5.0
2      5.0
3      5.0
4      9.0
5     12.0
6     12.0
7     12.0
8     12.0
9      8.0
10    17.0
11    17.0
12    17.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Select only the relevant values, i.e. where 'boolean' = 1

```
>>> on_values = rolling_max_value[df.boolean == 1].unique()
>>> on_values

array([ 5.,  9., 12., 17.])
```

The rows where 'new_boolean' = 1 are the ones where 'value' belongs to `on_values`

```
>>> df['new_boolean'] = df.value.isin(on_values).astype(int)
>>> df

    value  boolean  new_boolean
0       1        0            0
1       5        1            1
2       0        0            0
3       3        0            0
4       9        1            1
5      12        0            1
6       4        0            0
7       7        1            0
8       8        1            0
9       2        0            0
10     17        0            1
11     15        1            0
12      6        0            0
```

**EDIT:**

OP raised a good point

> Does this also work if I have multiple columns with the same value and they have different booleans?

The previous solution doesn't account for that. To solve this, instead of computing the rolling max, we gather the row labels associated with rolling max values, i.e. the rolling `argmax`or `idxmax`. To my knowledge, `Rolling` objects don't have an `idxmax` method, but we can easily compute it via `apply`.

```
def idxmax(values):
    return values.idxmax()

rolling_idxmax_value = (
    df.rolling(min_periods=1, window=4)['value']
      .apply(idxmax)
      .astype(int)
)

on_idx = rolling_idxmax_value[df.boolean == 1].unique()

df['new_boolean'] = 0
df.loc[on_idx, 'new_boolean'] = 1
```

Results:

```
>>> rolling_idxmax_value 

0      0
1      1
2      1
3      1
4      4
5      5
6      5
7      5
8      5
9      8
10    10
11    10
12    10
Name: value, dtype: int64

>>> on_idx

[ 1  4  5 10]

>>> df

    value  boolean  new_boolean
0       1        0            0
1       5        1            1
2       0        0            0
3       3        0            0
4       9        1            1
5      12        0            1
6       4        0            0
7       7        1            0
8       8        1            0
9       2        0            0
10     17        0            1
11     15        1            0
12      6        0            0
```

Comment: Does this also work if I have multiple columns with the same value and they have different booleans?

Comment: Good point, I didn't account for that. I have edited my post with a more robust solution. It should work now.

Comment: It works, but for my usecase there is still one issue: my indey-column is of type datetime and it seems like it does not work if this is the case. How would handle this? Temporarily add a column with values 0 to len-1 and set this as index? And if so, how do I add this column?

Comment: Just reset the index first by adding `df = df.reset_index()` before defining `rolling_idxmax_value`. The datetime index will be added to `df` as a new column.

Answer (score -2):

I did this in 2 steps, but I think the solution is much clearer:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
id value  boolean
0        1        0
1        5        1
2        0        0
3        3        0
4        9        1
5       12        0
6        4        0
7        7        1
8        8        1
9        2        0
10      17        0
11      15        1
12       6        0'''),delim_whitespace=True,index_col=0)

df['new_bool'] = df['value'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=4).max()
df['new_bool'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if ((x['value'] == x['new_bool']) & (x['boolean'] == 1)) else 0, axis=1)
df
```

Result:

```
    value   boolean new_bool
id          
0   1   0   0
1   5   1   1
2   0   0   0
3   3   0   0
4   9   1   1
5   12  0   0
6   4   0   0
7   7   1   0
8   8   1   0
9   2   0   0
10  17  0   0
11  15  1   0
12  6   0   0
```